# Why is class, interface, or enum expected?

Tags: java, enums

How and why am I getting the compiler error ("class, interface, or enum expected")? Here is the code:

```
public class RolloverCounter{
    private int counter=0;
    private int max;
    public RolloverCounter(int a){
      if(a<0){
        max = a;
      }
    }
    public void increment()
    {
       for(int i=0;i<=max;i++)
       {
         counter++;
         System.out.println(counter);
         if(counter==max){
           counter=0;
         }
       }
    }
    public void decrement(){
        for(int i=0;i<=max;i++)
          counter--;
        if(counter<0)
        {
          counter=max;
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
   }
   public String toString() {
      return counter;
   }
   public void reset(){
      counter = 0;
   }
}
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Can you post your exception?

Answer (score 4):

Your `toString()` method isn't returning a `String`,

```
public String toString() {
  return counter;
}
```

should be something like

```
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(counter);
}
```

Finally, you appear to have an extra closing brace (at the end) in your code as posted.

Comment: Thank you I either missed that in the book or it was not covered yet